# Cannot access SMB share hosted on Ubuntu from Windows 10

Tags: cifs, smbclient

Attempting to access SMB share on Ubuntu from my Windows 10 host fails with "session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED".

Windows 10 has SMB1 disabled:

```
PS C:\> Get-SmbServerConfiguration | Select EnableSMB1Protocol, EnableSMB2Protocol

EnableSMB1Protocol EnableSMB2Protocol
------------------ ------------------
             False               True
```

Accessing folder on Ubuntu:

```
sudo smbclient -L <host> -U Flowneee%<password> -m SMB2
```

results in:

> session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED

and:

```
sudo mount.cifs //<host>/net_shared ~/Desktop/net_shared/ -o user=Flowneee,password=<password>,vers=2.0
```

results in:

> mount error(95): Operation not supported

What am I doing wrong, and how to mount this folder to my Linux machine without enabling SMB1?

**UPD 1**

I can't find samba logs, nothing in /var/log/samba/.

Errors from output:

> SPNEGO login failed: The request is not supported.
>
> session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED

Full output:

```
INFO: Current debug levels:
  all: 10
  tdb: 10
  printdrivers: 10
  lanman: 10
  smb: 10
  rpc_parse: 10
  rpc_srv: 10
  rpc_cli: 10
  passdb: 10
  sam: 10
  auth: 10
  winbind: 10
  vfs: 10
  idmap: 10
  quota: 10
  acls: 10
  locking: 10
  msdfs: 10
  dmapi: 10
  registry: 10
  scavenger: 10
  dns: 10
  ldb: 10
  tevent: 10
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
INFO: Current debug levels:
  all: 10
  tdb: 10
  printdrivers: 10
  lanman: 10
  smb: 10
  rpc_parse: 10
  rpc_srv: 10
  rpc_cli: 10
  passdb: 10
  sam: 10
  auth: 10
  winbind: 10
  vfs: 10
  idmap: 10
  quota: 10
  acls: 10
  locking: 10
  msdfs: 10
  dmapi: 10
  registry: 10
  scavenger: 10
  dns: 10
  ldb: 10
  tevent: 10
Processing section "[global]"
doing parameter workgroup = WORKGROUP
doing parameter server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
doing parameter dns proxy = no
doing parameter log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
doing parameter max log size = 1000
doing parameter syslog = 0
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
doing parameter panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
doing parameter server role = standalone server
doing parameter passdb backend = tdbsam
doing parameter obey pam restrictions = yes
doing parameter unix password sync = yes
doing parameter passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
doing parameter passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
doing parameter pam password change = yes
doing parameter map to guest = bad user
doing parameter usershare allow guests = yes
pm_process() returned Yes
lp_servicenumber: couldn't find homes
added interface enp0s3 ip=fd4c:27d3:8b01:0:1c88:cbd0:748d:eff2 bcast= netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
added interface enp0s3 ip=fd4c:27d3:8b01:0:31aa:b1e4:2d56:fc70 bcast= netmask=ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
added interface enp0s3 ip=192.168.1.46 bcast=192.168.1.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
Netbios name list:-
my_netbios_names[0]="FLOWNEEE-VB-XUB"
Client started (version 4.5.8-Ubuntu).
Opening cache file at /var/cache/samba/gencache.tdb
Opening cache file at /var/run/samba/gencache_notrans.tdb
Adding cache entry with key=[AD_SITENAME/DOMAIN/] and timeout=[Чт янв  1 03:00:00 1970 MSK] (-1503660502 seconds in the past)
Could not get allrecord lock on gencache_notrans.tdb: Locking error
sitename_fetch: No stored sitename for realm ''
internal_resolve_name: looking up flowneee-pc#20 (sitename (null))
name flowneee-pc#20 found.
remove_duplicate_addrs2: looking for duplicate address/port pairs
Connecting to 192.168.1.37 at port 445
Socket options:
    SO_KEEPALIVE = 0
    SO_REUSEADDR = 0
    SO_BROADCAST = 0
    TCP_NODELAY = 1
    TCP_KEEPCNT = 9
    TCP_KEEPIDLE = 7200
    TCP_KEEPINTVL = 75
    IPTOS_LOWDELAY = 0
    IPTOS_THROUGHPUT = 0
    SO_REUSEPORT = 0
    SO_SNDBUF = 87040
    SO_RCVBUF = 372480
    SO_SNDLOWAT = 1
    SO_RCVLOWAT = 1
    SO_SNDTIMEO = 0
    SO_RCVTIMEO = 0
    TCP_QUICKACK = 1
    TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT = 0
 session request ok
Doing spnego session setup (blob length=320)
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.30
got OID=1.3.6.1.4.1.311.2.2.10
got principal=<null>
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
Starting GENSEC mechanism spnego
Starting GENSEC submechanism ntlmssp
     negotiate: struct NEGOTIATE_MESSAGE
        Signature                : 'NTLMSSP'
        MessageType              : NtLmNegotiate (1)
        NegotiateFlags           : 0x62088215 (1644724757)
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_UNICODE
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM    
               1: NTLMSSP_REQUEST_TARGET   
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SIGN   
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_SEAL   
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_DATAGRAM
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_LM_KEY 
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NETWARE
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NTLM   
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_NT_ONLY
               0: NTLMSSP_ANONYMOUS        
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM_DOMAIN_SUPPLIED
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_OEM_WORKSTATION_SUPPLIED
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_THIS_IS_LOCAL_CALL
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN
               0: NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_DOMAIN
               0: NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_SERVER
               0: NTLMSSP_TARGET_TYPE_SHARE
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_EXTENDED_SESSIONSECURITY
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_IDENTIFY
               0: NTLMSSP_REQUEST_NON_NT_SESSION_KEY
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_TARGET_INFO
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_VERSION
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_128    
               1: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_KEY_EXCH
               0: NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE_56     
        DomainNameLen            : 0x0000 (0)
        DomainNameMaxLen         : 0x0000 (0)
        DomainName               : *
            DomainName               : ''
        WorkstationLen           : 0x0000 (0)
        WorkstationMaxLen        : 0x0000 (0)
        Workstation              : *
            Workstation              : ''
        Version: struct ntlmssp_VERSION
            ProductMajorVersion      : NTLMSSP_WINDOWS_MAJOR_VERSION_6 (6)
            ProductMinorVersion      : NTLMSSP_WINDOWS_MINOR_VERSION_1 (1)
            ProductBuild             : 0x0000 (0)
            Reserved: ARRAY(3)
                [0]                      : 0x00 (0)
                [1]                      : 0x00 (0)
                [2]                      : 0x00 (0)
            NTLMRevisionCurrent      : NTLMSSP_REVISION_W2K3 (15)
SPNEGO login failed: The request is not supported.
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

**UPD 2**

```
 $ smbclient --version
 Version 4.5.8-Ubuntu

 $ dpkg -s smbclient
 Architecture: amd64
 Source: samba
 Version: 2:4.5.8+dfsg-0ubuntu0.17.04.5
```

Comment: Maybe this is of some help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70411/mount-t-cifs-operation-not-supported-but-can-connect-via-smbclient

Comment: @Lenniey you mean add `sec=ntlm`? Tried, didn't help.

Comment: Whats in your samba log? Also check your `smbclient` with `-d 10` (or between 3 and 10) and look for errors.

Comment: @Lenniey nothing in samba log (actually, /var/log/samba is empty), output added to question.

Comment: with the ntlm error you see, can you set that registry at 1? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/device-security/security-policy-settings/network-security-lan-manager-authentication-level

Comment: @yagmoth555 doesn't help

Comment: what version is the smbclient?

Comment: @yagmoth555 added to question

Comment: Maybe it's related to the Windows host configuration: Open Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc), go to *Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options*, Find the setting *Network Security: Restrict NTLM: Incomming NTLM Traffic* and verify it’s set to "Allow all"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

smbclient -L DomainController -W Domain -U DomainUsername

It will ask you for your password and it should be fine